# .htaccess rewrite redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some code which uses Rewrite engine in my .htaccess file and it specifies the directory for my SERPs. However when someone goes onto search/**QUERY**/ rather than search/**QUERY**/PAGE/ it displays a 404 error. Same with just search/.

I want it so that if someone just goes to search/**QUERY**/ that it redirects them to search/**QUERY**/1/ and for just search/ it redirects them to my homepage /. I have included a copy of my code below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&category=web&d=$2
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance, Callum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/?$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search/$1/1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&category=web&d=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple `RewriteRule` statements to accomplish this. (Make sure to omit the `[R]` flag on intermediate rules if you use it!)

The rule you posted will only rewrite if it's of the form `/search/query/n/`, so write a regular expression matching `search/query` that redirects to `/search/query/1`. Do the same to redirect home with no query.

Answer (score 0):

Try these additional 2 rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/$ /search/$1/1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ / [R=301,L]
```